# Types of W*- algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Searching to find a reference  for  "homogeneous type $I_{{\aleph}_0}$ W*-algebra", I was not successful. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might look in Dixmier's " Les C^*-Algebres et Leur Representations".$ I dk whether it is available in English

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Arveson's "An Invitation to C$^*$-algebras", Chapter 2; in particular, section 2.2.3.